# Java identifiers difference in errors

Tags: java

When we put # in the identifier name then it says illegal character but when we put other symbol such as !,@etc it says- '}' expected in java.Why is it so?

Comment: Can you be more specific of what you're talking about? Include some code? Error messages?

Comment: Likely because the latter are operators, while `#` isn't.

Comment: Please provide some examples in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The Parser can only give sensible error messages on what is there and stops as soon as possible.

It is sure that # is not allowed, so if it sees # it can just say: "stop it, this cant be correct" aka "illegal character".

Other characters *might* be correct, depending on whats coming after. When it says "} expected" then this could be a way to complete your sourcecode in a way that at least the parser is fine with it.